# Bipolar Transistor

Tags: bjt

why can't two discrete BJT have the same beta \$h_{fe} \$ value? In case of integrated circuit the beta value of transistor is almost same, but in case of discrete transistors it is not same. On which physical factors does the beta value depend?

Comment: *"In case of integrated circuit the beta value of transistor is almost same"* Only if they are on the same wafer and near to each other. I am sure that if you pick two transistors which come from two adjacent position of a wafer you will find that they are also nearly identical.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain on which factors the value of beta depends?

Comment: An interesting video to watch on the subject of creating silicon devices is [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvluuAIiA50).

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading, because of course two transistors **can** have the same beta value. But they **usually** do not have the same value and so we must design accordingly. The greater the distance between them when they are manufactured, both in time and space, the greater the difference in beta is likely to be.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it, showing your work and findings in detail.The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you sir for the information.

Comment: In a bag of nails, why aren’t they all exactly the same length?

Comment: Now it is more clear..I understood.

Answer (score 1):

When you buy a bag of 1,000 epoxy-packaged discrete 3-lead bipolar transistors, you have these mismatch causes

1) they may be from different manufacturers, from different diffusion (heating/annealing temperature-time plans) profiles, from different dates and different equipment with different calibration settings, from different wafer lots, from different wafers, and from non-adjacent locations on the wafers

2) to provide 1,000,000 devices of 2N2222, any junk that is not too leaky may be pulled out of wafer-stores and packaged and tested (its a "bipolar", ship it) and "2N2222" is printed on the black plastic; you were sold the bag of 1,000 out of the 1,000,000 lot just labeled 2N2222

If you want matched devices, then buy such as CA3046, originally from RCA. Also the CA3049 provides GHz devices as differential pairs.

Comment: Thank you Sir...

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about the *difference* in beta which depends on the variations during production process.

Two transistors which went through the same process and are physical next to each other on a wafer will have nearly identical parameters. This makes that transistor on a small die are nearly all identical. It also helps that they are thermally nearly the same.

If you take die from different wafers or from different corners of the same wafer you will find differences in their parameters.

As to

> on which factors the value of beta depends

you have to ask a silicon wafer expert.